# Why do I need to add null to showMessageDialog

Tags: null, joptionpane

Hi could someone please explain why I need null in the following code.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is + sName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need null, but it can be used instead of a parent component as the function is:

```
showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```